# JScript / WMI - How to check the class/type of an item?

Tags: javascript, class, types, wmi

In the code example below, how can I check what type/class objItem is? (i.e. whether it's a Win32_Service or not)

```
var wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 0x10;
var wbemFlagForwardOnly = 0x20;

var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2");
var colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);

var enumItems = new Enumerator(colItems);
for (; !enumItems.atEnd(); enumItems.moveNext())
{
   var objItem = enumItems.item();
   ...
```

I'd like to add a conditional at the end like:

if (objItem is of class Win32_Service)
{
  do stuff
}

Comment: It looks like you've accidentally created two accounts on this site - [743639](http://stackoverflow.com/users/743639/daveuk) and [774909](http://stackoverflow.com/users/774909/daveuk). You can [ask moderators to merge them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) so you can better keep track of your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check SWbemObject.Path_ [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393748%28VS.85%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

I think, there is no need to check type of class in this code. Because you are asking for `Win32_Service` class in your WQL. So, it will return that class only. You can just start getting attributes of `Win32_Service` like `objItem.Caption.`

Comment: That's actually not true, this call can return (at least) Win32_Service and Win32_SystemDriver. Either way, I am really interested to learn how to check the type/class of objItem as this will help me in other projects too.

Comment: @DaveUK: Win32_Service query should return only Win32_Service instances. If you query for Win32_BaseService, you get both Win32_Service and Win32_SystemDriver instances.

Comment: @Uros: This is true for `SELECT` queries, but the `ASSOCIATORS OF` query can return both, as in [Dave's other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6134484/113116).

Comment: @Helen: Thank you for the update. This is true if you use Associators Of queries, if you don't use the ResultClass clause to limit the returned instances, a query can return instances of more than one WMI class.